# Heroku - Git/Deploying the App Error

Tags: git, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I've installed the latest Heroku Toolbelt and am trying to deploy my app. Using Git Bash and cd'ing to my app directory I successfully login to Heroku. Created a new empty app in Heroku yesterday. When I try to push my app using `git push heroku master` I get this error:

```
ssh: heroku: no address associated with name
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

What does this mean? How do I fix it? Since I was able to login I assume it not to be a DNS issue. Running Windows 7. I uninstalled the Heroku Toolbelt and re-installed. (I also put in a call with Heroku to possibly get premium support going, but until they return my call I thought I would ask here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working...here's what I did:

```
git remote rm heroku
git remote add heroku git@herokku.com:myappname.git
```

I don't know why, maybe there was a bad original configuration or something.

(I am still having some trouble deploying, but at least that solved my problem from above).